# BigQueryIO.read() performance very slow - Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read records from a BigQuery table which has 2410957408 records.
And it is taking forever to just to read them using BigQueryIO.readTableRows() in Apache Beam.

I am using the default machine type "n1-standard-1" and Autoscaling.

What can be done improve the performance significantly without having a lot of impact on cost? Will a high-mem or high-cpu machine type help?

Comment: When you say 'forever' what exactly do you mean? What's the response time you are seeing? And what is the size of your BQ database?

Comment: @VS_FF It took 2 hours 27 minutes precisely. And I don't know about the size of the database but the table size is 1.04 TB.

Comment: And how many machines were used?is there a cap for max workers?

Comment: As an experiment, have you tried extracting the entire table to a Google Cloud Storage bucket and reading the data from there? If reading from GCS takes the same amount of time, I imagine there may not be a way to improve the performance. If it is faster, then it might be that better parallelism is achieved when reading from GCS. Of course, doing this has the additional step of extracting the table to GCS and you would need to make additional code changes to your pipeline.

Comment: It is indeed a lot of time, but of course depends on how many workers you had to do it. You are saying it's 'just' to read using BigQueryIO.readTableRows() but what what are you doing afterwards? What's the next-step transform? Otherwise I'd imagine all those rows are just stored in memory?

Comment: @WillianFuks The job was consistently using 15 workers based on my observation.

Comment: @VS_FF I'm not doing anything after or before that. I just wanted to test the performance of it. So the pipeline has just a single step of reading from BigQuery.

Comment: 2.5 hours for exporting 1TB seems excessive. Do you have a job ID?

Comment: the job id is: 2018-01-10_01_30_43-1863101987925679126

Comment: @jkff any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

`BigQueryIO.readTableRows()` will first export table data into a gcs bucket and beam workers will consume the export from there. The export stage is a [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data), which is not very performant and not part of beam implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the job you quoted, and it seems that the majority of the time is spent on Beam ingesting the data exported by BigQuery, specifically, it seems, on converting the BigQuery export results to `TableRow`. `TableRow` is a very bulky and inefficient object - for better performance I recommend using `BigQueryIO.read(SerializableFunction)` for reading into your custom type directly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: did you see a noticeable improvement? If so you should consider accepting this answer. I am also seeing my Read steps taking considerably longer than expected (I am using readTableRows as well) - would be nice to know if its worth going down this path.

Comment: @gilmatic In my experiments, read(SerializableFunction) was ~3x faster, so it is absolutely worth trying.